# Encoding hyperlink address in word document using c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to encode Hyperlink address in word document.

word documnet path is :`c://Users/Administrator/Dropbox/Tool`

```
finalURL=HttpUility.Urlencoding("http://www.Example.com/services/samplepage.aspx");

//finalUrl after encoding http%3a%2f%2fwww.Example.com%2fservices%2fSamplepage.aspx
```

replacing hyperlinks with Encrypted Url and bookmarks:

```
 docTemp.Bookmarks["FirstName"].Range.Text = "Prasanna";

foreach (Word.Hyperlink hyperlink in docTemp.Hyperlinks)
                        {
                            if (hyperlink.Address.Contains(@"mailto:"))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            hyperlink.Address = finalURL;

                        }
```

finally saving word documnet:

```
saveAsFileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}_{2}.doc", @"C:\Email_Sent", contactName, TodayDate.ToString().Replace(':', '_').Replace('/', '_'));
 docTemp.SaveAs(saveAsFileName);
```

But in word document taking  Url as (word document localpath+EncryptedUrl)

```
http://../Users/Administrator/Dropbox/BDETool/http%3a%2f%2fwww.Example.com%2fservices%2fSamplepage.aspx
```

I need exact Encrypted url :

```
http%3a%2f%2fwww.Example.com%2fservices%2fSamplepage.aspx
```

for hyper link address

Answer (score 0):

I got solution to my question

encode only parameters or part left after "?"

example , if your url is :

```
  "http://www.Example.com/services/samplepage.aspx?name=yourname&age=35"
```

code to encode:

```
byte[] Bdata= ue.GetBytes("name=yourname&age=35");
encryptdata= Convert.ToBase64String(Bdata);
sFinalURL = string.format("http://www.Example.com/services/samplepage.aspx?{0}",encryptdata)
```

OR

```
sFinalURL =string.format("http://www.Example.com/services/samplepage.aspx?name={0}&age={1}",yourname,35);
```